# Retrievedata from maps intent

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to know if there is a way to retrieve data from maps intent, like the duration of the trip or the distance or trigger something in my app when the user arrives at the destination and if there is no way how can I calculate that?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Your question will get more attention if you explain your problem more specifically.

Comment: To calculate distance and durations you can use [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start)